# Calculate memory usage of a tree structure in C++

Tags: c++, memory, tree, trie

I have a tree structure

```
struct TrieNode {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, TrieNode> children;
    std::vector<std::string> terminals;
};
```

Some details about its usage:

- The tree is not modified after it's been populated.
- The keys in unordered map are short strings (do not exceed 5 characters).

This structure can grow very large. And I need to calculate its size in memory. This size does not need to be very precise.
Are there any existing approaches to do that?

If no I was thinking of these options:

1. I can keep track of modifications to this structure separately.
2. Use a custom allocator for containers that keeps track of the space (is there a common implementation for that?).
3. Overload `new` operator for my structure to keep track of memory (not sure how to keep track of insertions into `vector` after that).
4. Calculate the size after the tree was populated by traversing the entire tree (last resort as for the large tree it would take really long time but the result is more precise).

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Is there a tree class encapsulating this? I would track it there.

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes. This structure is completely incapsulated in another class.

Comment: So long as the tree is fixed after it's been populated, I think "Calculate the size after the tree was populated by traversing the entire tree" won't take too much extra time, because the time complexity is `O(n)`, which reaches the lower bound of the input.

Comment: node count and overall string length (terminals) seem like useful metrics. Abstractions like that might be more useful than "memory" which would be implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The last one. I have following reasons:

1. It's the simplest among the four approaches.
2. because the tree is fixed after populated, lazily evaluating the size makes more sense, because:

   - when the size is not used, we can save the time spend on calculating the size.
   - It won't take extra time, for the time complexity is also `O(n)`, the only extra time spend is call on recursive functions.
3. it avoids the presence of global variable